# How to select text with the cursor without Force Touch?

Tags: iphone, ios

On iPhones with force touch, you can force touch on the keyboard to start to move the cars around in the text you were typing. Then, you can force touch again, to select the word that is under the cursor, and if you want you can now move the cars around some more to change the size of the selection.

How can I do the same thing on iPhone 13 (that doesn't have force touch)?

I would like to select text, without lifting my finger away from the keyboard to touch on the text itself

Comment: Are you asking how to simulate force touch on a device which doesn't have force touch, or how to select text on such a device?

Comment: @nohillside how to select text

Comment: Please do some research (https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/select-and-edit-text-iph1a9cae52c/ios).

Comment: @nohillside I intended my question to be about selecting text without touching the text

Answer (score 1):

While holding space and the cursor at the start or end of the desired selection range, tap anywhere on the faded keyboard to start selecting (e.g. with another hand’s finger) then continue dragging the cursor using the space bar to make the selection.

Comment: Is there a way to select word-wise?

Comment: This is a nice tip. I've been finding frustratingly that the controls are the wrong way round; after touching with a second finger I always instinctually try to move the selection using the second finger, but that does nothing and you can't tell selection mode is even active